Meaning of 相 in 讓僑胞擁有與國內民眾相類似之教育資源
讓僑胞擁有與國內民眾相類似之教育資源
What does 相 mean? Is this a typo? The sentence without it 讓僑胞擁有與國內民眾類似之教育資源 seems perfectly fine.

I think 相類似 is shortened for "相當類似" - "comparatively similar", a phrase is often seen in academic/official writings.

讓僑胞擁有與國內民眾相類似之教育資源 - Allow/let/permit overseas Chinese to possess "comparatively similar" educational resources as domestic people.


No. It means "mutual". If you want to say "comparatively similar", you use "相對"

@ZhenRanZR My opinion is that "相類似" is abbreviated from "相當類似", which is a non-absolute term and means "relatively/comparatively similar". Both "相對類似" and "相互類似" would be acceptable as well.

I'm native and I would say that ONLY “相互類似” is ok here.

“相类似”在汉语中通常表示两个事物之间有相似之处或相近的特征。这个表达在常用的语境中并不包含“相对类似”的意思。为了更准确地表达“相对类似”的概念，通常会使用“相对而言比较类似”或者直接用“相对类似”这样的表达。
比如：这两个产品的功能相类似。（表示功能上有相似之处）
这两个产品的功能相对类似。（表示功能上有一定的相似，但不完全相同，强调一种比较的关系）
因此，“相类似”不能完全替代“相对类似”，后者更适合用来强调两者在比较中的相似度。——ChatGPT

http://ccl.pku.edu.cn:8080/ccl_corpus/search?q=%E7%9B%B8%E7%B1%BB%E4%BC%BC&q1=%E5%BE%88%E7%9B%B8%E7%B1%BB%E4%BC%BC&LastQuery=%E5%BE%88%E7%9B%B8%E7%B1%BB%E4%BC%BC&start=0&num=50&index=FullIndex&outputFormat=HTML&encoding=UTF-8&isForReading=no&patternNature=&dir=xiandai&startTime=&endTime=&xiandaiStartTime=&xiandaiEndTime=&maxLeftLength=30&maxRightLength=30&neighborSortLength=0&orderStyle=score&scopestr=&search=%E6%9F%A5%E8%AF%A2#             check here for the corpus.

ZhenRanZR I opine 相類似 is a compound word from the sentence - "讓僑胞擁有與國內民眾相對(之下)類似之教育資源", or "讓僑胞擁有與國內民眾相當(和)類似之教育資源". Note that both have the implication of "相比教之下類似", which makes a better sense in this case.

相 means 'mutual'

讓僑胞擁有與國內民眾類似之教育資源 = Let overseas Chinese have educational resources similar to those at home.


讓僑胞擁有與國內民眾相類似之教育資源 = Let overseas Chinese and those at home having educational resources similar to each other

I agree 相 is redundant here. If we say "making A similar to B", there's no need to state "it also makes B  similar to A"  but it is not ungrammatical.
We mostly use 相類似 (similar to each other) where two things independently become similar to each other, in this case, the similarity is mostly coincidental
Example:
The domestication of rice in Asia and wheat in Europe have a similar background
亞洲水稻的馴化和歐洲小麥的馴化有著相類似的背景

相类似 = 相似 = 相类 = 相像 = 相(mutually) + similar = similar = 类似
So it’s not a typo but it’s not necessary either.


What does 相 mean?

相: has many shades of meaning, one of which is: 共同: [together;jointly]
鲁孟孙、 叔孙、 季孙相勠力劫 昭公——《韩非子·内储说下》(Was a while ago!)
The English word same also has this sense of together:
same: Gothic samana "together," Dutch zamelen "to collect," German zusammen "together")
(Birds of a feather flock together!)
类: [kind;class;type;category]
似: 相类，像: same kind, like
类似: [analogous;similar] 大致相像 literally: kind same kind
相类似: similar, (or the famous: same same )
相当: 两方面差不多;配得上或能够相抵
让侨胞拥有与国内民众相类似之教育资源
Enable (our) countrymen abroad have similar educational resources to those at home.
